# Passing customerID with a feedback table in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have two tables in my database:

```
customer
feedback
```

A 'foreign key' is in `feedback` table which is `customerID`.
I want to know which customer gives feedback through their id.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for the right query to get all feedbacks by a given customer (customerID)

Comment: yes that's later for sure but first when customer gives feedback i want to insert his ID with form.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select customerID from customer where customerID in (select distinct customerID from feedback);
```

Hope these query does what you want.

Comment: Well, thanks for the help.
But i want to pass customerID through feedback form so when they give feedback their id will insert into database along feedback information.

Comment: I did't get what you want to do.You have mentioned something else in your question.

Comment: Are you taking user email or phone number in your feedback form?

Comment: Yes, I'm taking both.

Comment: Is email or phone your primary key?

Comment: customerID is the foreign key in 'feedback' table

Comment: i did it.
Thanks